# Using memset in a CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, memset

This seems like an obvious issue, but Google turns up nothing interesting. Is it legal to use `memset` in a CUDA kernel such as:

```
__device__ void myKernel()
{
    int array[10];
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
    // ...etc...
}
```

(I know `int array[10] = {0};` is probably better, but this is just an example of a more complicated case.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as described in [Appendix B of the programming manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations), `memset`, as well as  `memcpy`, `malloc`, and `free` (the latter two only on Compute capability >= 2.0 devices) are supported in device code.